# How to find the max date in an array?

Tags: jquery

How to get max date from an array? I tried this, but it is returning invalid date

```
var dates = [2016/11/10,2016/11/20,2016/11/30]
var maxDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, dates));
```

Can anyone share any idea to find the maximum date.

I used Jsfiddle to workout here is that code

```
var data = [ ['2015/04/21'], ['2015/04/21'], ['2015/04/22'], ['2015/05/23'], ['2015/04/24'], ['2015/04/29']]

var dates = []; for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { dates.push(new Date(data[i][0])); }

Array.prototype.max = function() { return Math.max.apply(null, this); };

Array.prototype.min = function() { return Math.min.apply(null, this); };

alert("Max: "+new Date(dates.max())+"\n\n"+ "Min: "+ new Date(dates.min()));
```

Which is working fine on jsfiddle but not on development environment

Comment: Is that your actual array? If so, it's invalid syntax. The dates need to be stored as strings, or in a `Date()` object. Also, I assume by 'max' date you mean the latest date?

Comment: Please edit your question and format any additional code you want to add - it's not readable in comments

Comment: above code working fine on Jsfiddle but on development it is not working

Answer (score 2):

```js
  function find(){ 
     
  var data = [['2015/04/21'], ['2015/04/21'], ['2015/04/22'], ['2015/05/23'], ['2015/04/24'], ['2015/04/29']]
  var dates = [];
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
  {
   dates.push(new Date(data[i][0]));
  }
   
  var maxDate=new Date(Math.max.apply(null,dates));
  alert(maxDate);
  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="copy-times"  onclick="find()">find max</a>
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
var fmdt = fncgetDBFormatDate($("#<%=txt_Date.ClientID %>").val());

var todt = max();

if (fmdt != '' && todt != '') {
  if (fmdt > todt) {
    errMsg = "Date should be lesser than cheque maximum date ";
  }
}

function max() {
  var dates = [];
  var data1 = $("#jqxgrid2").jqxGrid('getrows');
  for (i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    var val1 = $('#jqxgrid2').jqxGrid('getcellvalue', i, "Date");
    dates.push(new Date(convert_date(val1)));
  }

  Array.prototype.max = function() {
    return Math.max.apply(null, this);
  };

  var maxdate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, dates));
  return convert_date(maxdate);
}

function convert_date(str) {
  var date = new Date(str),
    mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
    day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
  return [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("/");
}
```

Comment: The formatting of this really should be fixed. Please also consider giving more context for this as code-only answers are discouraged.